# ReactJS navbar will not load 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a navbar to my ReactJS website and I am trying to add a navbar to my website.
 It need the navbar to be on 100% width. I tried using 'width: 100%;'. But it will not make the header 100% .
Here is my Code:

ReactJS:

```
import React from 'react';

import './Header.css';

function Header() {
    return (
        <nav className="header">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <p>   </p>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <p>   </p>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
            <p>   </p>
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
       </nav>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

CSS:

```
.header > a {
  background-color: #171A25;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 33px;
}
.header {
    background-color: #171A25;
    align-items: center;
    word-spacing: 33px;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: It does take the entire width when I run your snippet.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering what I could do to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `<p>` tags.

```css
.header > a {
  background-color: #171A25;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 33px;
}
.header {
    background-color: #171A25;
    align-items: center;
    // justify-content: space-around;
    // display: flex;
    word-spacing: 33px;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        
            <a href="#">About</a>
            
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
          
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
       </nav>
```

Comment: I tried this code and it shows all of the links in completely different places.